# Guess the conector DVL Edition?

Tags: connector, identification, hacking

Here is a challenge we have a connector on a certin dvl(Doppeler Velocity Logger) and we cant get data from it. So we got a pinout,but without knowing pin 1 on the connector or what type of connector it is we cant do anything so here are some pics, I must note that my google search terms havent turned up anything yet but i will post update if they do. Good luck to anyone thats helping me. :)
[[image: Connector Female?][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUG2e.jpg)

[image: Connector Mail?]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Anyway there is also written on the connectors FD6030 FD5285
and again good luck and thanks in advance.
EDIT: We are trying to get rs232-1

[3]:

Comment: It might help if you say what a "DVL" is.

Comment: DVL Doppeler Velocity Logger - Special tool for tracking movement underwater. This is a connector on it no documentation for it though besides a bare bone electrical scematic.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet FCI makes this connector (or tyco) It has the same pitch as an SCA2 connector and has the same style of markings as an SCA2 connector (which tyco and fci make, but are phasing out). They are probably no longer on the market as these connectors are a precursor to SCA2 probably 15 years or older. I'd blue wire the board at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the whole schematic. I bet there are ground connections somewhere. As the connections are asymmetric you can use those to find out where pin 1 is.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, GND is on pin23 and CHGND is on pin 25